# Infinite vector space norm equivalents

Tags: normed-spaces

Let X be a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space complete for the norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$. Further there exists $C>0$ such that $\forall x\in X: ||x||_2 \leq C ||x||_1$. Show that these norms are equivalent.

So I need to show that there exists a $D>0$ such that $D ||x||_1\leq ||x||_2 $ $\forall x\in X$, but how do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{nrm}[1]{\left\lVert {#1}\right\rVert}\newcommand{norm}{\nrm{.}}id_{1,2}:(X,\norm_1)\to(X,\norm_2)$ is a surjective continuous linear map between Banach spaces, so it's open by the open mapping theorem. $id_{1,2}$ is bijective, continuous and open, therefore it's a homeomorphism. $id_{1,2}$ beign a homeomorphism implies that $(id_{1,2})^{-1}=id_{2,1}$ is continuous, q.e.d.